# Integrate fractions

Tags: integration

I know there is a lot of answers on how to integrate with fractions, but I think they are very case specific.

I've tried integration with substitution, but I can't seem to get a useful answer.

I simply want to integrate $\int$$\frac{v}{g+\alpha\cdot v}dv$

Comment: $g$ and $\alpha$ are constants? and i assume that $*$ is multiplication, if it is you should use $\cdot$ or even $\times$

Comment: What do you get with the substitution $u = g +\alpha v$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write $$I = \int \frac{v}{g + \alpha v} \, dv = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int \frac{\alpha v }{g + \alpha v} \, dv = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int \frac{g + \alpha v - g}{g + \alpha v} \, dv$$ $$=\frac{1}{\alpha}[\int \, dv -g \int \frac{1}{g + \alpha v} \, dv]$$

I feel you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is an *improper* rational function.  So the first step, every time, is to re-write it as a polynomial plus a proper rational function.  We do this with polynomial long division:

$$\frac{v}{g+\alpha v} = \frac{1}{\alpha} -\frac{g/\alpha}{g+\alpha v}.$$

In this case, the polynomial is a constant.  The second term integrates as $\ln$ of something.